# Use exchange server for sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, email, alert, exchange-server, notifications

We have `Exchange Server` in our organization for email. Now that I have `SharePoint`, I want to create a domain user e.g: `sharepoint` and then create a mailbox in `Exchange Server` say: `sharepoint@mydomain.com`. And then use this email for my SharePoint messaging and notifications, etc.

How is this possible and what are the steps? I have tried to set the email settings from `Central Administration > System Settings` but to no avail, it does not even ask me to enter the credentials to verify the domain account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have exchange server in place then it is very much easy to configure the SharePoint outgoing's email. You dont need to enter the credential to configure the outgoing email.

For sharepoint 2013:

- Go to central admin > system settings > outgoing email settings
- On the Outgoing E-Mail Settings page, in the Mail Settings section, type the SMTP server name for outgoing email (for example, mail.example.com) in the Outbound SMTP server box.
- In the From address box, type the email address as you want it to be
  displayed to email recipients.
- In the Reply-to address box, type the email address to which you want
  email recipients to reply.
- In the Character set list, select the character set that is
  appropriate for your language.
- Click OK

Now, on the exchange side add your servers into exchange relay.https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263462(v=office.15).aspx

For SharePoint 2016, check this article. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34167.sharepoint-2016-outgoing-email-configuration-settings.aspx

Comment: I notice that you have not mentioned the Incoming E-Mail Settings, why is that?

Comment: But from your question what I understand you want to configure outgoing email? Do you want incoming too?

Comment: Yes, I plan on using incoming E-Mail from users. One question though, when you insert the name of outgoing account, why it does not ask you to verify your identity via password?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Skype for Business Server 2015 deployments for integration with Microsoft Exchange Server 2016, Microsoft Exchange Server 2013, Microsoft Exchange Server 2010, and SharePoint Server, both on-premises and online. The features listed in the following table are supported with all clients unless otherwise specified. For more information about client support, see Desktop client feature comparison for Skype for Business and Skype for Business Online client comparison tables at Clients for Skype for Business Online.